# How to receive uploaded file within object nodejs/multer

Tags: node.js, xmlhttprequest, multer

i have a change user profile avatar page .. im using XHR to upload the picture .. then recieving it with multer (backend).
the problem im facing is that the received data is empty , because im sending the picture inside and object

```
var loadFile = function(event) {
  //avatar file
  let file = event.target.files[0];

  let formData = new FormData();

  formData.append('userAvatarFile', file);

  customAjax({
    method: 'post',
    route: '/profileEdit/userAvatar',
    type: "multipart/form-data",
    data: {
      target: formData //the avatar file is inside this "data" object
  })
 };
```

**The problem :** as you can see im putting the 'formData' inside an object , but when i do that multer will not find the file , and have to send the formData like that .. How can i make multer read the file from inside the 'data' object ?

**Backend Part:**

```
//SET DESTINATION AND FILE NAME FOR THE UPLOADED IMAGES
const storage = multer.diskStorage({destination: __dirname + 
'/../views/resources/images/avatar',
filename: function(req, file, cb){
  cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now() + path.extname(file.originalname));
}});

//init upload for multer
const upload = multer({storage: storage,
  limits: {
  fileSize: 1000000
},
fileFilter: function(req, file, cb){
  checkFileType(file, cb);
}
}).single('userAvatarFile');

//SECURITY PART OF FILE UPLOADING
//check the uploaded files
function checkFileType(file, cb){
//Allowed ext
  const filetypes = /jpeg|jpg|png|gif/;
//check ext
  const extname= filetypes.test(path.extname(file.originalname).toLowerCase());
//check mime
  const mimetype = filetypes.test(file.mimetype);

  if(mimetype && extname){
    return cb(null, true);
  }else{
    return cb(new Error('Images Only!'))
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm suspecting the issue is might be at `checkFileType`, could you try to console.log what is the `file` or whether `req.body` have the data sent over?

Comment: no the check file type is working properly .. cause im using it in other location file (post picture) .

Comment: If you could upload it to a github repo, I will help to take a look. Its a bit hard to do it without all the other parts.

Comment: ok .. this is the project link https://github.com/salsa-project/crispy-talk and this is the live preview on heroku https://crispy-talks.herokuapp.com/wall/new

Comment: there is  alot of code inside .. go views>resources>js>app.js for the xhr part

Comment: and for multer backend part controllers>profileEditController.js

Comment: Ok cool, so the data that is missing, is actually the attached data field right? Not the photo. Just to be sure here.

Comment: i found the problem place is here   https://github.com/salsa-project/crispy-talk/blob/9254ee3244edac78007d6102099eb3640876a56e/views/resources/js/app.js#L41

Comment: but now when i set the `xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', "multipart/form-data");` i get this error `Multipart: Boundary not found`

Comment: Can you point me to which line of code block you're sending the xhr request?

I couldn't find the sample u post above

Comment: While looking at your code, i believe you're trying to simplify the xhr request to a few type, however this is making it hard for you to work with this problem. I've tried using postman to send form-data.

The upload works well, image is saved successfully.

The other appended formData is also captured by the backend at `req.body`

I believe the only thing for you to do is actually referencing the uploaded image address to ur DB.

Comment: yes the sample above was "abstracted" for the simplicity purpose .. and i didn't push latest code yet .. this is the part im using to upload the file from 'app.js' `var loadFile = function(event) {
    let image = document.getElementsByClassName('profile-header-avatar profile-edit-header-avatar')[0];
    image.src = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);
    let file = event.target.files[0];
    let formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('userAvatarFile', file);
    postItem('/profileEdit/userAvatar', formData, '', "file")
  };`

Comment: yes i tried to simplify XHR .. and i found the exact line that causing the problem .. look here https://github.com/salsa-project/crispy-talk/blob/9254ee3244edac78007d6102099eb3640876a56e/views/resources/js/app.js#L45

Comment: i was using JSON.stringify on a file .. by removing it now working like charm .. ty men for your time

Comment: Oh ya, do not use JSON.stringify on the file. form-data is transmitted using stream. you can read more on that too

Comment: Read more on this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Sending_and_retrieving_form_data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While working through the problem with OP, it seems that all `xhr` had been merged into a function to simplify all the request. However, the data is transformed by `JSON.stringify` before sending, which is not what `"multipart/form-data"` should do.

`"multipart/form-data"` is used to handle blob, which normal HTTP couldn't really handle without some compromise (like encoding base64 or others, which result in even larger size). `"multipart/form-data"` is basically a stream upload, so there will be chunks that is loaded to ur server. `Multer` is used to handle this.

You can read more about the `"multipart/form-data"` here
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Sending_and_retrieving_form_data

Comment: great answer and explication .. thank you :)